# App isn't launching in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

Ok, so as the title says, my Android app doesn't want to launch itself in a running emulator. The Emulator itself is a *Nexus 5* running *API 23* (*Android 6.0 Marshmallow*).

I know I should be asked how I wish to launch my application if the Emulator is off, from a window pop up which asks whether I want to use a running device or start one from AVD, however, I do not get this.

The code taken from my manifest is below. (If any other information is needed ask away and I will upload it)

*Image no longer available*

Comment: like CommonsWare said, don't post images when you can post code. code can be indexed ... (the contents of) an image cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a launcher activity. Hence, Android Studio does not know how to start a launcher activity for your app, and so it will not offer to run your app.

On your `LogInScreen` manifest entry, you replaced `android.intent.action.MAIN` with `com.example.michael.whatsuplondon.MAINACTIVITY`. Change that back to `android.intent.action.MAIN`.

Also, in the future, do not post screenshots of IDE windows, when you can post the actual text instead (e.g., of the manifest, in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, however, I found out that the main problem I was having was due to only having selected the 'build' to the left of the run button instead of the 'App' as a whole. This meant that the build was launching as I had a Java icon pop up but it wasn't launching in the emulator - pretty much a face-palm error haha!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your intent filter into:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```